# Are there poisons that affect only mammals but not reptiles

Tags: mammals, species, toxicology

Are there poisons that affect only mammals but not reptiles or crustaceans?
E.g. hemotoxins which affect hemoglobin but not hemocyanin or specific Na+ channels?
Looking for a "nice" poison/disease as idea for a fictional story to explain survival of reptiles/crustaceans vs. mammals.

Comment: "Reptiles" are not very different from mammals (compared to crustaceans).

Comment: Good candidates would likely be poisons originating from reptiles/crustaceans themselves...